# reviving image through sockets [Windows Store Apps - C# ]

Tags: image, windows-store-apps, filepicker

I'm receiving an image on a Metro app through network socket every 1 second, loading it in an array of bytes, then convert it to a BitmapImage and display it later. All of this work fine.

The image is changing  constantly on the other side. For some reason, it throws an OutOfMemory exceptions from now and then(like 1 in 10) . I fixed it by clearing the array of bytes every time the image is received. Now it works like charm.

See below for my main issue:

```
         public static BitmapImage imag;
         public static byte[] save = new byte[1];

if(recieved)
{
         await reader.LoadAsync(4);
         var sz = reader.ReadUInt32(); //read size
         await reader.LoadAsync(sz);   //read content
         save = new byte[sz];
         reader.ReadBytes(save);
         await ImgSrcFromBytes(save)

         Array.Clear(save, 0, save.Length);         //issue here !! 
} 



public async Task<ImageSource> ImgSrcFromBytes(byte[] a)
    {
       imag = new BitmapImage();

        var stream = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await stream.WriteAsync(a.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);

        imag.SetSource(stream);
        return imag;
    }
```

Now, i'm implementing a new function to save the image as a file if requested by the user with the code below, however, if i clear the array of bytes above, i get an unreadable image, but if i don't clear the array, i get a perfect image.

Note that no exceptions are thrown and both images have the same size.

```
       FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
       picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
       picker.SuggestedFileName = "capture.png";
       picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Png File", new List<string>() { ".png" });

       StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

       if (file != null)
       {
           CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
           await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, save);
           await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
           await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Image Saved Successfully !").ShowAsync();

       }
```

I hope i'm clear. It's a trade-off, if i clear the array, i will get no exceptions while receiving streams over sockets, but i won't be able to get a readable image when saving. and vice versa.